# Using Cucumber/Capybara, is there a non-brittle way to screen scrape?

Tags: ruby, capybara, nokogiri

Does anyone know of a Ruby gem out there which enables a robust way of identifying html field names and "screen scraping" the response data?

I have a Ruby/Cucumber framework running Capybara.  I have feature files which navigate a UI and input data.  I have a few screens from which I must collect data from fields.  In order to do that, I am using Nokogiri to get the response page html, and parse it.  The search string ({node} in my example below) can be rather complicated and brittle as it is navigating through various blocks of html.

```
page_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(session.html)
block = page_html.xpath(path)
result = block.at_xpath("#{node}")["#{value}"]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Nokogiri to parse the page rather than just using Capybara and its built in selectors (or your own custom selectors) to find the nodes you are interested in and accessing the value attributes on them?    find(<selector for the element>).value  -  find(:field, 'name of field).value - etc..

Comment: Like @TomWalpole said there isn't much of a reason to use Nokogiri if you already have access to Capybara's selectors. I would only use Nokogiri in the case I didn't need to traverse a UI and I just wanted raw data from a page.